# WPF - setting IsSelected on DataGridRow won't change the value in the bound object

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

The issue that I'm having is that I'm trying to use a DataGrid with multiple selection and I'm trying to select multiple without pressing the Ctrl key

In my view I have:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                   SelectedRows ="{Binding SelectedTags, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   CanUserAddRows="False">

        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="DataGridRowPreviewMouseDownHandler"></EventSetter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                 Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Mode = TwoWay}"
                 MaxWidth="25" MinWidth="25">
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And in my code behind:

```
    private void DataGridRowPreviewMouseDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            var row = GetVisualParentByType((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource, typeof(DataGridRow)) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null)
            {
                row.IsSelected = !row.IsSelected;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static DependencyObject GetVisualParentByType(DependencyObject startObject, Type type)
    {
        DependencyObject parent = startObject;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            if (type.IsInstanceOfType(parent))
                break;
            else
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        return parent;
    }
```

My model class is

```
public class Tags : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _isSelected = value; RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The CataContext for the GridView is an ObservableCollection

The issue is that when I set in the DataGridRowPreviewMouseDownHandler

> row.IsSelected = !row.IsSelected;

The model is not updated.

Without the DataGridRowPreviewMouseDownHandler all works fine. With it, the initial binding doesn't work(eg. if I set one tag's IsSelected to true when adding to the ObservableCollection, it will be displayed as not selected). Any idea why?

How do I trigger an update on the bound object to the row?

Comment: Have you tried adding SelectionMode="Extended" to your datagrid and check the behaviour ?

Comment: It's on the first row afeter the items source. 
The issue is that with SelectionMode="Extended" you can select multiple rows, but you have to press the Ctrl key. I'm trying to achieve the same behavior without pressing the Ctrl key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF DataGrid SelectedItems - keeping multiple selected while left clicking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953511/wpf-datagrid-selecteditems-keeping-multiple-selected-while-left-clicking)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2957514/2470362

Comment: My issue is that following a similar example to this one, the binding does not work anymore, the UI looks fine, but the bound properties don't reflect what is shown in the UI.